# Authenticate AmazonS3 client without Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload to an S3 bucket using the [AmazonS3 client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html). I create it using the following code:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
   .withRegion(clientRegion)
   .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
   .build();
```

This uses the `.aws/credentials` file to authenticate. My problem is that when I push this to an EC3 environment (not locally), it fails because the environment doesn't have this `.aws/credentials` file on it and we are not allowed to add the credentials for security reasons.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AWS IAM Role to authenticate AWS services. AWS IAM Role should have AWS S3 necessary permission and attach the role to an EC2 instance. Whenever you make S3 request, it will authenticate through IAM role. By the way, you don't need credentials file in the application.

Comment: Are you saying that I should be able to do change permissions and remove the `withCredentials` line?

Comment: @Haych You should keep the code. When deploying to an EC2 instance, you should have IAM role policy with S3 permission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance profile the EC2 then will be able to access whatever resources are in your account as long as your instance profile role has those permissions. [Instance profile creation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html)

Comment: The first line is that I should skip this step if it is an EC2 instance?